# How is this animation implemented

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

Can you take a look at [JWT](http://www.jwt.com) and suggest what library was used to create the animation of DIV transition from one place to another? 
Also, any suggestions about the overall algorithm used to load the RSS and the construct columns/rows out of it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what seems to be their "main" js file: http://www.jwt.com/js/compiled.js, and you can see that they're using a pretty huge variety of plugins, along with some self-composed stuff, probably for the feed and special case handling of data.

**EDIT:** the jQuery [masonry plugin](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) handles repositioning divs, while [quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) can handle filtering with animations. These are just examples of plugins that does those kinds of things, there might be other plugins as well.

Comment: What about div displacement and re-ordering once buttons at the top are used or when clicking on an entry?

Comment: @Acolyte I added some references in there for you. Just some of the plugins I've used previously.

Answer (score 1):

This effect can be achieved using jquery.take a look [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/)
Try the options in the dropdown like scale,size,fold etc